# Maximum average Rating per week

Tags: mysql

I Have Image Table with each Image get rated

```
SELECT imagesrc,AVG (rating / total_votes) AS maximumrate FROM imagerate GROUP BY ImageSN order by AVG( rating/total_votes ) DESC  LIMIT 1
```

I got Maxmium average rated Image but I want Maximum Rated Image for a Week for that i searched and found this code below near to my requirement but I cant put them together to work

```
WHERE time BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)

imagerate structure is 

ImageSN (primary key)
imagesrc (imagepath)
time (uploaded at (date)) 
rating
total votes
```

need expert opnions HELP!

MODIFIED

```
$requestthree = 'SELECT imagesrc,AVG (rating / total_votes) AS maximumrate FROM imagerate  WHERE time >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+7 DAY
AND time < curdate()  - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY  GROUP BY ImageSN order by AVG( rating/total_votes )DESC LIMIT 1';
```

Now query is giving me Max Rating Per week But if my database has two images with HIGH AVerage RATING I want to get Which Images Get more votes

I tried to add

`GROUP BY total_votes` as MAX() will Make this query invalid

Comment: does the week always ends at the query execution date?

Comment: this is also part of confusion but i want it like this week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For last week try to add this:

```
SELECT imagesrc,AVG (rating / total_votes) AS maximumrate 
FROM imagerate
WHERE time >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND time < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
GROUP BY ImageSN order by AVG( rating/total_votes ) DESC  LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response How i can write these two query together ?

Comment: i did like that but please explain it a bit so i can understand this code better

Comment: you can read about mysql date functions here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Can you check my new edit i want to get that max rating which have high total votes Please check